# Invalid and mismatched count

Tags: sql, oracle, date

When I run below query:

```
select trunc(create_date), count(*) as num_created
from mytable WHERE create_date >= (sysdate -9)
group by trunc(create_date) order by 1;
```

The output:

```
06-MAR-24   7
07-MAR-24   1826
08-MAR-24   1135
09-MAR-24   1253
10-MAR-24   1119
11-MAR-24   1446
12-MAR-24   1400
13-MAR-24   2498
14-MAR-24   1633
15-MAR-24   616
```

And when I run below query:

```
select trunc(create_date), count(*) as num_created
from mytable WHERE create_date >= (sysdate -10)
group by trunc(create_date) order by 1;
```

The output:

```
05-MAR-24   165
06-MAR-24   1020
07-MAR-24   1826
08-MAR-24   1135
09-MAR-24   1253
10-MAR-24   1119
11-MAR-24   1446
12-MAR-24   1400
13-MAR-24   2498
14-MAR-24   1633
15-MAR-24   616
```

Wondering why the count for 06 March becomes 1020 from 7. (and so on) What I am missing here or doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get if convert `create_date >= (sysdate -9)` to `create_date >= trunc(sysdate) -9` and like this `create_date >= (sysdate -10)` to `create_date >= trunc(sysdate) -10`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type that consists of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** contains those 7 components and it is **NEVER** stored in a human readable format.

When you use `SYSDATE - 10` then you are subtracting 10 days from the current instant and it will have the same time component so:

```sql
SELECT SYSDATE,
       SYSDATE - 10,
       TRUNC(SYSDATE - 10)
FROM   DUAL
```

Outputs:

| SYSDATE | SYSDATE-10 | TRUNC(SYSDATE-10) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-15 22:34:11 | 2024-03-05 22:34:11 | 2024-03-05 00:00:00 |

and:

```sql
WHERE create_date >= sysdate - 10
```

will get all the results that are in the last 10 days from the current instant; which means that you will get a partial day's results.

If you want a full day then use `TRUNC` to truncate the time-component to midnight:

```sql
WHERE create_date >= TRUNC(sysdate -10)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0SM4G0bn)

Comment: Nice explanation @MT0. Thanks a lot. Now I have the clarity and figured what I was missing. Much appreciated.